# Meaning of "X has shrunk our costs by 25%"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

Here's the sentence:

> The productivity improvements have shrunk our costs by 25%.

Does it mean our costs are now 25% or 75% of what they were?

Answer (score 5):

To reduce something **by** an amount, fraction or percentage, is to make it that amount, fraction or percentage less, smaller, lighter, etc.

If your costs are $100:

If you reduce them **by** 25%, your costs become $75.

If you increase them **by** 25%, they become $125.

If you reduce your costs **to** 25% (of the previous amount), they become $25.